# Conectar o BD sql server ao sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle, sqldeveloper

estou tentando conectar meu sql developer ao sql server, porém não está funcionando. A senha e usuário estão corretos. Sabem qual o problema?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: pelo sqlmanager studio vc consegue conectar?

Comment: @AdrianoGomes, sim, consigo. Porém quero conectar ao sql developer.

Comment: ja tive esse problema, porém precisava acessar com o usuário SA, precisei liberar o acesso remoto e depois habilitar o usuário SA. Veja se isso te ajuda: http://www.systematiza.com.br/site/?page_id=837 e https://atendimento.redehost.com.br/hc/pt-br/articles/218105357-Habilitando-usu%C3%A1rio-SA-no-SQL-Server-2012

Comment: @AdrianoGomes, excelente. Habilitando o usuário `sa` foi o suficiente para conectar o sql developer ao sql server. Obrigado.

Comment: @AdrianoGomes, peço que coloque seu comentário como resposta da minha pergunta, desta forma, poderei fechar de forma correta a pergunta. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme dito nos comentários acima, basta habilitar o usuário SA. Um exemplo de como fazer isso está no nesse [link](http://www.systematiza.com.br/site/?page_id=837).

Comment: Obrigado. Ajudou muito.